# Unable to see log entries when running a test class

Tags: unit-test, debug

Apologies if this has been explained elsewhere but I cant find an answer specific to my problem.
I'm trying to test a trigger that prevents a contact from being entered if the last name is "INVALIDNAME" and the test is failing so I want to print the error from Database.insert() to see whats coming back because I think my assertion is correct. The problem is that although I can write to the debug log before calling Database.Insert(), nothing after that makes it to the log. So the question is, how come one part of the test can write to the log but another cannot?

Code below:

```
@isTest
public class TestRestrictContactByName {
    @isTest static void TestDeleteWithInvalidName() {
        Contact newContact = new Contact( FirstName = 'Bob',
                                          LastName = 'INVALIDNAME');     
        system.debug('This makes it to the debug log');
        Test.startTest();
        Database.SaveResult Result = Database.insert(newContact);       
        system.debug('This does not make it, even if I remove Test.startTest() above');
        system.debug('Error Message is: ' + Result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assert(!Result.isSuccess());
        System.assert(result.getErrors().size() > 0);   
        System.assertEquals('The Last Name "INVALIDNAME" is not allowed for DML',
                             Result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());      
    }
}
```

Comment: The debug statements should all appear. However, there's a maximum debug log file size. If you reach this limit, you'll get a truncated log back. How big is your log file?

Comment: The Database.insert is likely throwing an exception. To resolve, ensure you pass false as a second parameter to this method (which tells it not to throw an exception but rather to return a mix of successful and failed save results when a failure happens).

Comment: @PhilW Actually, that makes more sense; allOrNone=true throws a DML Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Database.insert` call has two forms of interest here:

1. The one you are calling, taking a list of SObjects to insert,
2. An overloaded version taking a list of SObjects and a boolean "allOrNothing" flag.

The first effectively calls the second passing in true. This then means that if any one record fails validation (including addition of an error onto a field e.g. in a trigger) then instead of returning a list of `Database.SaveResults` the method throws an exception. This exception will prevent the later code being executed.

If you call `Database.insert(newContact, false);` in your code then instead of the exception being thrown, you will get the save results and your code can continue its execution without being skipped.

Comment: That's spot on @PhilW. Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. Its actually a little embarrassing that I didn't figure this out myself, but that's what happens when you're tired I guess

Comment: No worries. We all look straight through stuff on occasion.